# Print an R vector vertically

Tags: r

I'm doing an analysis where I would like to change the printing of data from horizontal to vertical. For instance, when I do the following, here is the type of output I currently see:

```
> with(mtcars,sapply(split(mpg,cyl),mean))
       4        6        8 
26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```

I would like the output to be organized like this:

```
4    26.66364
6    19.74286
8    15.10000
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `stack()`,

```
with(mtcars, stack(sapply(split(mpg, cyl), mean)))
#    values ind
#1 26.66364   4
#2 19.74286   6
#3 15.10000   8
```

But `aggregate()` would probably be much nicer for this problem

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, mean)
#  cyl      mpg
#1   4 26.66364
#2   6 19.74286
#3   8 15.10000
```

Also, `tapply()` might be a better fit than `sapply()`, if you go that route.

```
stack(with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, cyl, mean)))
#    values ind
#1 26.66364   4
#2 19.74286   6
#3 15.10000   8
```

With `sapply()`, you're going to get a vector if the return values are only on one row, so you may want to use a different function for the calculations.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
cat(vector, sep = "\n")
```

This essentially creates a string of vector elements and prints to console with newline character.

Comment: Nice idea. Better than importing libraries just to print a vector

Comment: Unfortunately this drops the names, which is information the OP wanted (i.e. variable `cyl`).    
Changing to `cat(x, labels = names(x), fill=1)` would keep the names but if those name strings don't have same number of characters then the output would not be aligned.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
as.matrix( with(mtcars,sapply(split(mpg,cyl),mean)) )
  [,1]
4 26.7
6 19.7
8 15.1
```

By default matrix objects will be single column matrices. You could use:

```
as.data.frame( with(mtcars,sapply(split(mpg,cyl),mean)) )
```

But the name of the column will be ugly, IMO.

Comment: That did the trick, except for the first row `[,1]`, which I will tolerate. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to do this, with a bit less typing, is two transposes: `t(t(...))`.

Comment: Too may upshifts for me.

Answer (score 5):

Package [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) can also be used for vertical output:

```
mtcarsdt = data.table(mtcars)

mtcarsdt[,mean(mpg),by=cyl]
   cyl       V1
1:   6 19.74286
2:   4 26.66364
3:   8 15.10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Some output functions have the option `flip`, e.g. stargazer (for summary statistics). That may help you, too.

Answer (score 0):

with `dplyr`'s pipe you can also do:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl `mean(mpg)`
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     4        26.7
2     6        19.7
3     8        15.1
```